# Error installing Python packages on an AWS Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, python, packages, libraries

I am trying to install the Ansible control server on Ubuntu 14.x (an AWS instance).

When trying to install the dependencies, I saw an error.  I'm not sure what I need to do.  Is this an ignorable error?

Here is what I entered:

```
pip install paramiko PyYAML Jinja2 httplib2
```

Here is what I saw at the end:

```
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-0JTKy4-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pycrypto
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I went to /root/.pip/pip.log. I saw this:

```
 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.linux-x8     6_64-2.7/src/MD2.o
1149
1150 src/MD2.c:31:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
1151
1152  #include "Python.h"
1153
1154                     ^
1155
1156 compilation terminated.
1157
1158 error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: do you have gcc installed?

Comment: google for the error. there are several stack overflows about that issue

Comment: Try installing python-dev `apt-get install python-dev`